# Proving uniform continuity of $f(x) = x \sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ on $(1,2)$ directly from the definition.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-verification, continuity, uniform-continuity

**Before this is marked as a duplicate, I have already looked at the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560486/uniform-continuity-of-fx-x-sin-frac1x-for-x-neq-0-and-f0-0#) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778579/uniform-continuity-of-x-sin-frac1x?noredirect=1&lq=1).**

I believe my question is different because I want to do this proof directly from the definition. The proof given at the first link uses the property of compactness, Lipschitz continuity and derivatives to support the argument. However, my professor's real analysis approach has not been that of metric spaces and, additionally, Lipschitz continuity has not been discussed yet so I'd like to avoid them for now and attempt this proof directly from the definition. I'm interested in a proof similar to the second answer given on the first link but, unfortunately, there are no comments on whether or not it is correct.

The question is to determine whether or not $f(x) = x \sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ is uniform continuous on $(1,2)$.

I present my own attempt:

Given $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta= \frac{\epsilon-1}{2}$ Then $|x-y|<\delta \implies$ $$\left | f(x)-f(y)\right | =\left | x\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-y\sin \left(\frac{1}{y}\right) \right|=
\left |(x-y) \left( \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{1}{y}\right) \right) -x\sin \left(\frac{1}{y} \right)+y\sin \left(\frac{1}{x} \right)\right|
\leq \left |(x-y) \left( \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{1}{y}\right) \right)\right| + \left|-x\sin \left(\frac{1}{y} \right)+y\sin \left(\frac{1}{x} \right)\right|$$

$$\leq \left |x-y \right| \left |\left( \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{1}{y}\right) \right)\right| + \left|-x\sin \left(\frac{1}{y} \right)+y\sin \left(\frac{1}{x} \right)\right|$$

$$\leq 2\left |x-y \right|+1 < 2\cdot (\frac{\epsilon-1}{2})+1=\epsilon$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The answers at the duplicate link are both upvoted, one is accepted by the asker, and the other has 10 upvotes, hence *very well* received by the community.  The fact that a highly upvoted answer has no comments is not sufficient reason to ask the question again.

Comment: @amWhy The answer has **3** upvotes, not 10. The one with 10 is the one that was accepted by the OP which is the one that uses the approach I'm trying to avoid. 
3 is definitely not a very highly upvoted answer. It's possible that perhaps 3 other users that used a similar approach upvoted that answer to attract some attention.

Comment: @amWhy I hope that explains why I had to post a separate question. I really need input on this approach, but now that it has been marked as a duplicate how will I get any assistance on this approach? Again,  I'll add that that answer had no comments  and only 3 upvotes so surely one is not immediately expected to conclude that it was _very well received by the community_.

Comment: Yes, I see I got the descriptions mixed up.  But for an answer posted three years after the original question, the fact that it received 3 upvotes indicates it was very well received.  (Later posts, over time, are less visible, though they are always reviewed, and it is only the rare very good late answers that get more than an upvote or two.

Comment: @amWhy I get you, but what if I need input on _this specific approach_? I did, after all, also add a tag of proof verification. And according to the guidelines, if a  question has been asked before and already has an answer but those answers do not _fully address your question_, you can ask a new question.

Comment: I did not see your proof-verification tag.  I will reopen, and perhaps emphasize that you are seeking feedback on your proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that $\delta = \frac{\epsilon - 1}{2}$ is not a very good choice of $\delta$: what if $\epsilon-1<0$? Here is a correct solution.

We have that $|\sin(s) - \sin(t)| = \left|2\overbrace{\sin\left(\frac{s-t}{2}\right)}^{\leq \frac{s-t}{2}}\underbrace{\cos\left(\frac{s+t}{2}\right)}_{\leq 1}\right| \leq |s-t|$ for any real $s,t$.

This implies that $|\sin \frac{1}{x} - \sin \frac{1}{y}| \leq \left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right| = \left|\frac{x-y}{xy}\right| \leq |x-y|$ since $xy \geq 1$, since $x,y \in (1,2)$.

Consequently, observe that $$\left|x\sin \frac{1}{x} - y \sin \frac{1}{y}\right| = \left|x\left(\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\right) + \sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)(x-y)\right| \leq \overbrace{|x|}^{\leq 2}\underbrace{\left|\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\right|}_{\leq |x-y|}$$ $$+  \  \underbrace{\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\right|}_{\leq 1}|x-y| \leq 3|x-y| 
 < \epsilon$$ provided we choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$.

Comment: Thanks! Now I see why my delta isn't a good choice. I was thinking, what if, say, I took the absolute value instead? i.e $\delta =| \frac{\epsilon - 1}{2}|$? Then realised there'd be a problem if the numerator were $0$. So my question is that is it a general strategy to not have the choice of $\delta$ depend on a value that includes something like $\epsilon -a$ where $a>0$?