# continuity and uniform continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis

I have to discuss the continuity and uniform continuity of the following function

$f: x \in (0, +\infty )   \longrightarrow f(x) = x* sin \frac{1}{x}$

the limit for $x \rightarrow 0^+$ doesn't exist

while $ \lim_ {x \rightarrow + \infty }  x* sin \frac{1}{x} =1$.

However $f(x)$  is continuous $\forall x \in (0, + \infty)$  because

$\forall x_0 \in (0,+ \infty), \lim _{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x)= f(x_0)$

The definition of uniform continuity says that
$$ \forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta >0 : \forall x,y \in (0 +\infty ), |x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$$

Now I don't know how to verify this definition for all the values of the domain.
Or I could find a counterexample...
Can someone help me to understand what to do in this case?

Comment: f is continuous at 0 as well, and uniform continuous

Comment: Why would the "limit for $x\to0^+$ not exist"?

$$\lim_{x\to0} x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)=0$$ because $$0\leq|x\sin(1/x)|\leq x\to 0$$ for $x\to0$.

Comment: Please, take a look at this,  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778579/uniform-continuity-of-x-sin-frac1x?noredirect=1&lq=1