# Explanation of uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I want to show the uniform continuity in $\mathbb R$ for the function $f(x)=x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

I know that from here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560486/uniform-continuity-of-fx-x-sin-frac1x-for-x-neq-0-and-f0-0?noredirect=1&lq=1) it contains the solution but it uses a derivative but I want a solution purely using the definition in extension of a function. I have a solution that says that The limits $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=1$ and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow-\infty}f(x)=-1$ are both finite, so $f$ has a continuous extension to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R} \cup[-\infty, \infty]$, which is compact. Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

However, I have a question about this solution, how does a finite limit have anything to do with a continuous extension? Also, why can they say $[-\infty, \infty]$? How can one use a closed interval on $\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using some more advanced notions belonging to the field of topology. In topology, we equip arbitrary sets with a notion of open and closed sets. In this context, nothing keeps us from taking the set $(-\infty,\infty)$ and adding two points $A$ and $B$ and just defining that $A$ is smaller than all elements of $(-\infty,\infty)$, while $B$ is larger than all those elements. And since this is intuitively what we expect $\pm\infty$ to behave like, we call them $\pm\infty$ instead, and call the entire set $[-\infty,\infty]$. And it turns out to be compact.

Now we can still talk about limits and continuity of functions on this set in much the same way as we do in our usual setting. Do you agree that the function $g:(0,1)\to\mathbb R,~x\mapsto x^2$ can be continuously extended to $[0,1]$, since its limits as $x$ goes to $0$ or $1$ are finite? It's the exact same situation for your function $f$.

Now the argument goes that since this continuous extension is defined in a compact set, and continuous functions on compact sets are automatically uniformly continuous, the extension is uniformly continuous. Also, uniform continuity is preserved when restricting the domain of a function, so if an extension of a function is uniformly continuous, then so is the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

You can prove that if $f:[a,\infty )\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and such that $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)$ exist, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty )$.